# How does branch.io deep link works on expo?

Tags: react-native, expo, branch

I've been following the instructions provided in the Expo config-plugins GitHub repository to integrate Branch.io into my Expo 49 app.

Everything seems to be working fine, and I can successfully open my app with the Branch sub-domain "yxevl.app.link." However, I'm encountering an issue when passing parameters to this sub-domain. For instance, when I try to open "yxevl.app.link/Home?email=example@gmail.com," my app only receives the generic scheme://open.

I initially suspected this might be an issue with Expo Go, so I decided to build and test the app in production. Unfortunately, the problem persists.

Here's my app.json configuration:

```
        {
      "expo": {
        "name": "AdGo Driver",
        "slug": "adgo-driver",
        "version": "0.1.0",
        "orientation": "portrait",
        "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
        "scheme": "adgo-driver",
        "userInterfaceStyle": "dark",
        "packagerOpts": {
          "config": "metro.config.js",
          "sourceExts": [
            "expo.ts",
            "expo.tsx",
            "expo.js",
            "expo.jsx",
            "ts",
            "tsx",
            "js",
            "jsx",
            "json",
            "wasm",
            "svg"
          ]
        },
        "splash": {
          "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
          "resizeMode": "cover",
          "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
        },
        "assetBundlePatterns": [
          "**/*"
        ],
        "ios": {
          "supportsTablet": true,
          "bundleIdentifier": "com.adgo.driver",
          "buildNumber": "1",
          "infoPlist": {
            "UIBackgroundModes": [
              "location",
              "fetch",
              "audio"
            ]
          }
        },
        "android": {
          "adaptiveIcon": {
            "foregroundImage": "./assets/images/adaptive-icon.png",
            "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
          },
          "package": "com.adgo.driver",
          "versionCode": 1,
          "config": {
            "googleMaps": {
              "apiKey": ""
            }
          },
          "permissions": [
            "android.permission.CAMERA",
            "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"
          ]
        },
        "web": {
          "bundler": "metro",
          "output": "static",
          "favicon": "./assets/images/favicon.png"
        },
        "plugins": [
          "expo-router",
          [
            "./plugins/react-native-code-push-expo-plugin",
            {
              "android": {
                "CodePushDeploymentKey": ""
              },
              "ios": {
                "CodePushDeploymentKey": ""
              }
            ]
          ],
          [
            "expo-document-picker"
          ],
          [
            "expo-task-manager"
          ],
          [
            "expo-notifications",
            {}
          ],
          "react-native-background-fetch",
          [
            "expo-gradle-ext-vars",
            {
              "googlePlayServicesLocationVersion": "20.0.0",
              "appCompatVersion": "1.4.2"
            }
          ],
          [
            "expo-camera",
            {}
          ],
          [
            "expo-image-picker"
          ],
          [
            "onesignal-expo-plugin",
            {
              "mode": "production"
            }
          ],
          [
            "@config-plugins/react-native-branch",
            {
              "apiKey": ""
            }
          ]
        },
        "experiments": {
          "tsconfigPaths": true,
          "typedRoutes": true
        },
        "extra": {
          "router": {
            "origin": false
          },
          "updates": {
            "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
          },
          "eas": {
            "build": {
              "experimental": {
                "ios": {
                  "appExtensions": [
                    {
                      "targetName": "OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension",
                      "bundleIdentifier": "com.adgo.driver.OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension",
                      "entitlements": {
                        "com.apple.security.application-groups": [
                          "group.com.adgo.driver.onesignal"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "projectId": ""
          },
          "oneSignalAppId": ""
        },
        "owner": ""
      }
    }
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I’m having trouble to open my app after used branch. It crashes when the app starts.